# May I apply for a US visa from Australia or must it be from Pakistan?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani national who is migrating to Australia in December 2016 on State sponsored business visa through the government of Australia. I intend to visit the USA in April 2017 and return to Australia.

Can I apply for a US visa from Australia, or do I need to apply from Pakistan?

Comment: The homepage of the respective embassy in Australia should list the requirements for applying there. In general, you need residency in the country of the embassy/consulate. How to prove that depends on some details -- hence, you need to look at that web page.

Comment: The US doesn't care. You can apply from anywhere, even if you're in a country as a tourist. The only problems with that are whether the embassy you apply to can verify your documents, which is possibly not true if you aren't a resident of that country, and whether you have the necessary documents at all.

Comment: Do you want to apply now or after you migrate to Australia?

Comment: @DCTLib the US doesn't require visitor visa applicants to reside in the country where they're applying.

Answer (score 2):

Details of how to apply for a nonimmigrant visa for USA from Australia are available at the [U.S. Embassy & Consulates in Australia](https://au.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/) site.

There is no mention there that the applicant must be an Australian citizen to be able to use that service. So, yes, you may apply for a US visa from Australia and, no, you do not need to apply from Pakistan.